# API Gateway Websockets - Close client connection after receiving data

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to have API Gateway close the connection to a client as soon as it has sent data to a route I've specified?

I want to achieve this to avoid clunking up connections when using a fire-and-forget request (not closing the connection from the client would improve the performance), or will API Gateway automatically get rid of idle connections after a certain amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always invoke the disconnect on the connection after certain time . Application needs to remember the connection id . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there's a way to see a list of all currently active connections? (mostly for debugging purposes)